# Sqlmap post data

Tags: http, sql-injection, sqlmap

I was trying to run sqlmap with method POST but I got this error:

`[CRITICAL] no parameter(s) found for testing in the provided data (e.g. GET parameter 'id' in 'www.site.com/index.php?id=1')`

Now, I know that for POST method I must run sqlmap with data flag (e.g `--data="name=value"`)
but my form input data has no name and data is send as a string.

How can I use sqlmap in this situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use asterisks `*` to specify your injection point. Try this:

```
python sqlmap.py -u "http://www.example.com/index.php?id=1" --data="POST_STRING_HERE*" --dbs
```

Note the `*` in the data string. SQL map will ask if you want to process the wild cards, enter `Y` there. It will ignore all the parameters and inject the payloads in place of `*`.

From the [docs](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/FAQ#how-to-use-sqlmap-with-mod_rewrite-enabled):

> Append an asterisk, *, to the place where sqlmap should check for
>   injections in URI itself. For example, ./sqlmap.py -u
>   "http://target.tld/id1/1*/id2/2", sqlmap will inject its payloads at
>   that place marked with * character. This feature also applies to POST
>   data. Multiple injection points are supported and will be assessed
>   sequentially.